# Redux-toolkit create action prepare doesn't add the values for Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm following the official example here [redux-toolkit reference](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data#preparing-action-payloads) and trying to type the PayloadAction as followed :

```js
import {
  createSlice,
  PayloadAction,
  nanoid,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

type MyObjectType = {
  uuid: string
  anotherProp: string
  // ...
}

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'oneSlice',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    addSomething: {
      reducer(state, action: PayloadAction<{x: string; anotherProp: string}>) {
        const { x, uuid, anotherProp } = action.payload // got an error here on uuid
        // do something with { x, uuid, anotherProp }
        // I need to use it as index : state.something[uuid] = { uuid: uuid, anotherProp: anotherProps }
      },
      prepare(x: string, anotherProp: string) {
        return {
          payload: {
            uuid: nanoid(),
            x,
            anotherProp,
          },
        }
      },
    }
  }
})
```

However I got an error trying to destructuring `action.payload`. How to infer the `uuid` attribute of `action.payload` ?

I've come to a weird solution where I pass the whole object type in PayloadAction and modify the uuid inside `prepare()`

```js
...

    addSomething: {
      reducer(state, action: PayloadAction<{x: string; myobject: MyObjectType}>) {
        const { x, myobject } = action.payload 
        // there is no problem here
      },
      prepare(x: string, myobject: MyObjectType) {
        myobject.uuid = nanoid()
        return {
          payload: {
            x
            myobject: myobject
          },
        }
      },
    }

...
```

Is there a better way to resolve this ?

Comment: `action: PayloadAction<{x: string;} & MyObjectType>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add it:

```
      reducer(state, action: PayloadAction<{x: string; anotherProp: string; uuid: string}>) {
```

This will still warn you if you define something that doesn't acutally exist:

```
      reducer(state, action: PayloadAction<{x: string; anotherProp: string; foo: string}>) {
```

but just requesting a subtype (like you do) is not an error, so it won't warn you